# Will SET operation improve the performance of the stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a question, which may be silly questions for many. But I would like to understand it clearly or whatever I have understood and learned is wrong.

I basically use SET NOCOUNT ON at the beginning of the stored procedure, other SET operations I will use based on the need. Recently, one of my stored procedures went for a review. The guy given a comment like we need to use all the below-mentioned SET operations which are mandatory and standard as well. And all these SET operations will increase the performance of the stored procedure which is getting called in C# from API.

```
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
   SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
   SET ARITHABORT ON 
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
   SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON 
   SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
```

I know what each SET operations are for, but would like to know how this will increase the performance of the stored procedure which is getting called in API.

I searched, but I didn't get the proper thread. Need inputs here.

Comment: Please read [this in full](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. This link clarifies and it has more information.

Comment: You should have "the guy" read it too, sounds like he has generalized quite a bit.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . You have to be a little careful here.  Most of these have no conceivable relationship to performance, but they might be reasonable coding standards across an organization.  That said, I would configure the servers and then disallow `set` in code, rather than enforcing a code block in each stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you @AaronBertrand. Very good read.